# Sanitizing a string in php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, string, xss

How to check if the string contains any tags <>. I need to sanitize my string from xss attacks or attacks like that. 
I am looking for a function which can santize my string in javascript and php.

This is what I have for java script , please let me know if this is correct ?

```
function parseThisString(strcode) { 
    var scripts = new Array();         
    while(strcode.indexOf("<") > -1 || strcode.indexOf("</") > -1) { 
        var s = strcode.indexOf("<");
        var s_e = strcode.indexOf(">", s);
        var e = strcode.indexOf("</", s);
        var e_e = strcode.indexOf(">", e);
        scripts.push(strcode.substring(s_e+1, e)); 
        strcode = strcode.substring(0, s) + strcode.substring(e_e+1); 
    }
    if (scripts.length >  0) { return 1; } else { return 0; }
}
```

Can you guys show me any solid string sanitizing function in php ? I found this answer but I didt know how to transilate this function to a single return with 0 or 1 (yes or no) .
[What is the correct way to detect whether string inputs contain HTML or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419038/what-is-the-correct-way-to-detect-whether-string-inputs-contain-html-or-not)

Please help me here . Thanks.

Comment: By sanitising, do you want to make the HTML "safe" so that you can output it onto the page, do you want to remove all HTML tags, or do you want a binary "yes/no" for whether a string contains HTML tags?

Comment: yes , HTML "safe", so that I can output links and all.

Answer (score 3):

You can escape any html tags using `htmlspecialchars()`.

```
$string = htmlspecialchar($old_string);
```

You can remove all html tags from string using `strip_tags()`.

```
$string = strip_tags($old_string);
```

But if you wanna know if there's html tags in the string, you can use this function, combinated with `strip_tags()`.

```
function hasHTML($string) {
    if ($string != strip_tags($string))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I have used strip_tags(). ya I will check if the string != strip_tags($string)